# PHP SoapServer: How to select XSD 'choice' value?

Tags: php, soap, xsd, wsdl

I'm developing a SOAP service using the PHP `SoapServer` class and a corresponding WSDL.

The SOAP Schema definition (WSDL) allows "choice" types: It requires EITHER of the contained properties, like this:

```
<xsd:element name="AnswerA">
    <xsd:complexType name="typeA">
      <xsd:choice>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="propB" type="ns0:typeB" /> -->
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="propC" type="ns0:typeC" />
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

I am serving such a construct with a SoapServer that knows its SOAP types via a classmap. The corresponding PHP class for typeA would look as follows:

```
class TypeA {
    private $propB = null;
    private $propC = null;

    public function setPropB(TypeB $b) { $this->propB = $b; }
    public function setPropC(TypeC $c) { $this->propB = $c; }
    public function getPropB() { return $this->propB; }
    public function getPropC() { return $this->propC; }
}
```

I now deliver a PHP SoapServer that responds with a Soap message containing those type, but only with propC set:

```
$typeA = new TypeA();
$typeA->setPropC(new TypeC('someValue'));
// ...
$mySoapServer = new SoapServer(/*....*/);
$mySoapServer->addFunction('myfunction');
function myfunction() {
    return $typeA;
}
```

This is working, BUT in the answer, I always get "propB", and never "propC", even if "propB" is null while "propC" is not set:

```
<!-- ..... -->
<AnswerA>
    <propB></propB>
</AnswerA>
<!-- ..... -->
```

This is not utterly wrong, it's just not what I want: In the case of an XSD "choice" type, I want to deliver that property that has a value (well, "null" is also some kind of value, I guess). So how can I "tell" the PHP SoapServer which property to deliver in case of an XSD "choice" type?